# Inserting data into a remote database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a web/login page, where if a user is in certain location then they can be able to insert data in the database based on their location.

**For example,** if we have two users bob and max, one in A(bob) and the other in B(max).

If bob logs into the system username... bob password... 123 location.. A, he should be able to to insert his data on the database located on his PC same as max but they should use a single application.

Now my question is how can I achieve this. For example I've a login script below which is communicating with my localhost (A) and i also want to include a remote connection to my other PC on the LAN (B), using Mysql database installed on both computers, I can connect to Mysql database using Mysql workbench but how can I do it using a script in PHP?

**login page**

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['login'])){
            include 'includes/config.php';

            $uname = $_POST['uname'];
            $pass = $_POST['pass'];

            $query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE uname = '$uname' AND pass = '$pass'";
            $rs = $conn->query($query);
            $num = $rs->num_rows;
            $rows = $rs->fetch_assoc();
            if($num > 0){
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['uname'] = $rows['uname'];
                $_SESSION['pass'] = $rows['pass'];
                echo "<script type = \"text/javascript\">
                            alert(\"Login Successful.................\");
                            window.location = (\"admin/index.php\")
                            </script>";
            } else{
                echo "<script type = \"text/javascript\">
                            alert(\"Login Failed. Try Again................\");
                            window.location = (\"login.php\")
                            </script>";
            }
        }
    ?>
```

**connection.php**

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $db = "cars";

    $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    if($conn->connect_error){
        echo "Failed:" . $conn->connect_error;
    }
?>
```

> Configuring two connection scripts is what i have in mind, but i don't
>   think it will work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Comment: I don't understand your Problem. just make 2 variables for your Connections $connLocal and $connRemote, with different Hosts ?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo   yes thats what i want to do,but how do i integrate them in the login script

Comment: So you want both of them to write in both databases ? or do you want both of them to write in the same database ? or you want to write some stuff in DB A and some other stuff in DB B ? And what Problem do you have ? Connection to the DB on the remote host ?

Comment: "*..Configuring two connection scripts is what i have in mind, but i don't think it will work.*" Better Check Yourself Whether It's Working Or Not.